# Second value is coming back as undefined in action in redux/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, redux, axios

I want to call a second action but only when the first action has completed its request. I have tried to just call it after the first action but I soon realized that I needed to data from the response for the second function to work properly.

**WORKING VERSION FROM PREVIOUS PROJECT**:

```
onSubmit(values) {
    this.props.createPost(values, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/posts');
    });
  }
```

---

```
export function createPost({title, content}, cb) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts`, {title, content}, {
      headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')}
    })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({
          type: CREATE_POST,
          payload: response
        });
      })
      .then(() => cb())
      .catch((error) => {
        if(error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.data);
        }
        console.log("Problem submitting New Post", error);
      });
  }
}
```

**END OF WORKING VERSION**

For some reason anything I pass through the second value is returning undefined and therefor giving me an error of cb not defined.

Here is the function or action I am calling:

```
export function sortOffers({ currency, name, geolocation, category, btc, sys, zec }, cb) {
  console.log(cb);
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .get('/API/offers/sort', {
        params: { currency, name, geolocation, category, btc, sys, zec },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: SORT_OFFERS, payload: response.data });
        dispatch(reset('sorter'));
      })
      // .then(() => cb())
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err);
      });
  };
}
```

I call this on another page after a form has been submitted like so:

```
   submitSort(values) {
    this.props.sortOffers(values, 12);
    // this.props.sortOffers(values, () => {
    //   this.props.filter(this.props.filterOption);
    // });
  }
```

The problem is I want to call this action `this.props.filter(option)` after it but I need for the first action to complete in order for it to work properly. Unfortunately cb is returning undefined in my action. I have tried this before and it worked just fine so Im not sure what I am doing wrong.

**WHOLE FILE:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { sortOffers } from '../../redux/actions/sortActions.js';
import { setVisibilityFilter } from '../../redux/actions/browser';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import PaginationField from './PaginationField';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import SorterForm from './SorterForm';
import selectForm from './selectForm';

class Sorter extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedField: '',
    };
  }

  submitSort(values) {
    this.props.sortOffers(values, () => {
      this.props.filter(this.props.filterOption);
    });
  }

  filterChoice(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectedField: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={{ margin: '100px 20px 0px 20px' }}>
        <form
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submitSort.bind(this))}
          style={{
            width: '100%',
            border: '1px solid #333',
            background: '#f9f9f9',
            padding: 16,
            margin: 16,
          }}
        >
          <Field onChange={this.filterChoice.bind(this)} name="selectForm" component={selectForm} />
          <SorterForm selectedField={this.state.selectedField} />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={reset}>
            Clear
          </button>
        </form>
        {/* {this.renderItems()} */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    itemSorted: state.sorter.list,
    offersFiltered: state.sorter.filter,
    filterOption: state.sorter.option,
  };
}

const dispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  sortOffers: offers => dispatch(sortOffers(offers)),
  filter: options => dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(options)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchToProps)(
  reduxForm({
    form: 'sorter',
  })(Sorter),
);
```

Comment: It looks like you are using `redux-thunk`, you may want to read this section on Promise handling while [dispatching asynchronous actions](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition)

Comment: So `cb` is undefined in your `console.log`?

Comment: Yes I will try this out here soon!

Comment: cb is still logging as undefined =/

Comment: Added an edit to show you my previous working version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code the
`sortOffers` signature says it is expecting one single parameter named `offers` that's why it's undefined in your action.

```
sortOffers: offers => dispatch(sortOffers(offers))
```

If you want to keep the Callback style you can catch the param and pass it down:

`sortOffers: (offers, cb) => dispatch(sortOffers(offers, cb))`

But I strongly recommend to follow **GProst** suggestion: Promise chain.

As you are now returning the Axios promise you can now use it like this:

```
submitSort(values) {
  this.props.sortOffers(values)
  .then(() => {
    this.props.filter(this.props.filterOption);
  });
}
```

Comment: Face-palm on missing that haha. Is there a reason returning the axios promise is better ? Or is it just preference or better practice? I am going to do it that way I was just wondering!

Comment: As `sortOffers` returns what the `dispatch` call returns it will be a promise.  If you return the Axios promise the success callback inside then(cb) will be executed only if it's resolved successfully. Otherwise it will be called always. 
You may say it's a style choice, but I like it because you don't need to do any additional calls on the action and/or pass parameters down, so it's kind of cleaner. Also as you are using redux-form it might be useful to listen promises rejections (something like responses with status code 400 ) and throw `SubmissionError` when it's the case.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your action you have to return the promise, that `axios` creates:

```
return (dispatch) => {
  return axios
    .get('/API/offers/sort', {
...
```

Then in your component you can chain this promise:

```
submitSort(values) {
  this.props.sortOffers(values)
    .then(() => {
      this.props.filter(this.props.filterOption);
    })
}
```

Comment: cb is still logging as undefined =/

Comment: You have `this.props.sortOffers`. Can you please show how you pass `sortOffers` function to component props?

Comment: Added the whole file for you at the bottom!